# Отдача JSON со SPRING MVC

Tags: java, spring

В `spring boot` есть такая замечательная штука для отдачи JSON'ов с автоматическим вытягиванием его из класса:

```
@RestController
public class TaskController {

    private DBService dbService = new DBService();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/tasks")
    @CrossOrigin
    public @ResponseBody List<TaskDataSet> tasks() {
        try {
            List<TaskDataSet> tasks = dbService.getAllTasks();
            return tasks;
        } catch (DBException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Если скормить этот код `spring mvc`, то получается следующая ошибка:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.ArrayList
```

Как мне сделать тоже самое в `spring mvc` правильно ?

Comment: `HTTP Status 500` вы получаете в браузере, какая ошибка на стороне сервере, есть стекстрейс?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Додайте зависимость в проект если у вас сборщик `maven` или соответствующее для `gradle`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Судя по описанию ошибки `spring` не может найти конвертер для маршалинга в `json`.

Чтобы исправить ошибку нужно:

- либо подключить его отдельно, как описал в своем ответе [@BogdanK](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/620922/10353),
- либо добавить `spring` зависимость:

  ```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
     <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  ```

Контроллер должен выглядеть так:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MyController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "check", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public List<Simple> check() {
      List<Simple> result = new ArrayList<>();
      result.add(new Simple());
      return result;
   }
}
```

А модель:

```
@JsonAutoDetect
public class Simple {
    private int value;
}
```